# How In ViewController function get set value combobox/ Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

In the application I use the component for creating/editing records: `Ext.window.Window`
In the window is the `combobox` field:

```
...
{                   
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: {
                    type: 'type-store'
                },                               
                fieldLabel: 'Type',                   
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id',                   
                queryMode: 'remote',                   
                name: 'type',
                reference: 'typecombo',
                store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    fields: ['id', 'name'],
                    data: [
                        {id:1, name:"Punkt1"},
                        {id:2, name:"Punkt2"},
                        {id:3, name:"Punkt3"},
                        {id:4, name:"Punkt4"}                                          
                    ]
                }),      
                listeners:{                    
                     afterrender: 'onAfterRenderCombo'                   

                }                           
            },
```

In ViewController created a function:

```
....
    onAfterRenderCombo: function (sender, record) {

       //How to get the combobox value set?
    },
....
```

I need to get the value exactly when I open `Ext.window.Window`
How can I get the combobox value if it is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want.

Since you are using the `afterrender` event, you can do this:

```
onAfterRenderCombo: function (combobox, opts) {

   // Print the combobox value (if it is set)
   console.log(combobox.getValue());
}
```

You can check the [afterrender API](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#event-afterrender) if you are not sure which variables it receives.

Cheers

Comment: Your example does not work! You can verify this by the example based on your answer that I prepared in [fiddle ]: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2spj

Comment: Indeed. The `afterrender` event is fired when you call `wind.show()`. Since you load the record after you show the window, the value you get will always be null. Try loading the record and then show the window.

Comment: Yes.When I set the window display after loading the record, then getting the value works. Thank